# How do I deploy a react website to github pages?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've tried following the github documentation and this video tutorial to a T https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq6EkzoZp4w and yet when ever I try and visit my site I simply get a 404 error, this a link to the gh-page repo https://github.com/Jseto97/jseto.me/tree/gh-pages. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check this, it is very good tutorial to deploy react app on github pages https://medium.freecodecamp.org/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project-c0ecbf317089